# Reinstall no CD OR USB

Tags: lubuntu, reboot, ubuntu-core, reinstall

My system is Ubuntu only, how do I completely reinstall Ubuntu from terminal deleting everything and resulting in a fresh install without USB OR CD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**(1) Backup Your Files**

MAKE SURE YOU'VE COPIED YOUR FILES AND DATA TO A SAFE PLACE, **NOT** ON YOUR COMPUTER.

**(2) Download Ubuntu 17.10**

Download the 17.10 ISO from ubuntu.com (ubuntu-17.10-desktop-amd64.iso) and save it in your `Downloads` folder.

**(2) Create a Partition to Boot the Live ISO From**

Make sure you've completed step #1!!!

Open the GParted application. If you don't have GParted, install it from the Software Center or use `sudo apt install gparted`.

In the top right of the gparted window, you must make sure your current hard disk is selected.
Since you mentioned you don't have a USB stick or CD, there  should be only be one option in the dropdown for you.
It will probably be somethig like `/dev/sda`, but make sure you have the right disk selected!

Use gparted to resize your disk and create about 3 GB of space at the end of the disk.

Then create a new primary partition in this space, and format it to the `ext4` file system.

*Note the name of the partition*; it may be something like `/dev/sda3/`.

You can close GParted now.

**(3) Mount the New Partition**

Open the Disks application and select the partition you created above. (The Disks application calls this a "Device", but make sure it is the same as the partition name you noted in step #3).

After selecting it, click in the "mount" icon.

Disks will mount the partition and will display the mount point; it will look something like `/media/nightx/xxxxx`.

*Make a note of the actual mount point*. For the rest of this answer, I will use `/media/nightx/xxxxx`, so replace as necessary. Make sure you can read and write to `/media/nightx/xxxxx` (try creating a text file and deleting it).

You can close Disks now.

**(4) Copy the Live ISO to the New Partition**

Open a terminal, and enter the following:

```
sudo cp ~/Downloads/ubuntu-17.10-desktop-amd64.iso /media/nightx/xxxxx
```

(Make sure `/media/nightx/xxxxx/ubuntu-17.10-desktop-amd64.iso` is owned by root; using `sudo` to copy the file ensures this).

**(5) Edit Grub to Boot the Live ISO**

In a terminal, do the following:

```
sudo gedit /etc/grub.d/40_custom
```

Copy the following into this file.

```
#!/bin/sh
exec tail -n +3 $0
# This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries.  Simply type the
# menu entries you want to add after this comment.  Be careful not to change
# the 'exec tail' line above.

menuentry "Install" {
    set isofile="/ubuntu-17.10-desktop-amd64.iso"
    loopback loop (hd<X>,<Y>)$isofile
    linux (loop)/casper/vmlinuz.efi boot=casper iso-scan/filename=$isofile noprompt noeject
    initrd (loop)/casper/initrd.lz
}
```

In the text above, replace `<X>` as follows:

- If your new partition name has an "a" (like "sda") replace `<X>` with "1"
- If your new partition name has a  "b" (like "sdb") replace `<X>` with "2"
- If your new partition name has a  "c" (like "sdc") replace `<X>` with "3"

In the text above, replace `<Y>` as follows:

- If your new partition name ends in "1" (like "sda1") replace `<Y>` with "1"
- If your new partition name ends in "2" (like "sda2") replace `<Y>` with "2"
- If your new partition name ends in "3" (like "sda3") replace `<Y>` with "3"

For example, if your partition name is "sda3", in the 9th line above, you should use...

```
loopback loop (hd1,3)$isofile
```

Also note, there are no angle brackets (`<` or `>`) in the the final text.

Finally, save the file (`/etc/grub.d/40_custom`) and exit Gedit.

Type the following to double check that your changes were saved and are correct:

```
cat /etc/grub.d/40_custom
```

**(6) Update Grub**

Now, update grub using:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Check the output and make sure you do not get any errors.  If you see errors, double check step #5.

**(7) Boot to the Live ISO**

Restart your computer.

Press the <kbd>ESC</kbd>.

You will see the Grub Menu.

(If you see your Ubuntu Login screen, you will need to restart and try hitting <kbd>ESC</kbd> at the right time).

One of the Grub options will be "Install", which you had configured in step #5.

Select "Install" using your arrow keys and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

If you get an error message (~ about Grub not being able to find a boot file), that means you did not set `<X>` and `<Y>` correctly in step #5.  You can return to step #5, and try different number combinations until you find the right designation for your new partition.  Be sure to execute step #6 each time you edit `/etc/grub.d/40_custom`.

**(8) Prepare to Install**

If you were successful, you will boot into the Ubuntu Live ISO directly from your hard disk!!

*Before you click on the installer, be sure to do the following...*

Open a terminal window by typing <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>ALT</kbd><kbd>T</kbd>. In the terminal, type the following:

```
umount -l /dev/sda3
```

Rememebr to replace `/dev/sda3` with the name of the new partition you noted in step #3.
This command tricks the installer into thinking this partition is unmounted; in reality, the Live ISO is being accessed from there.

**(9) Install Ubuntu**

Make sure you've completed step #1!!! (This is your last warning!)

Launch the Ubiquity installer to install Ubuntu.

During the install, you should select the option "Something else", so you can explicitly avoid formatting `/dev/sda3`.

The options "Erase Ubuntu..." or "Erase everything..." *may* work, but I don't have experience with these.  (If you try either of these options, please comment back if they worked).