# Can I install Ubuntu to an external disk without live booting from USB?

Tags: system-installation

Every install guide that I've seen involves putting a Ubuntu iso on a USB or CD and installing it that way. Is it possible to skip that middle man and install it directly to the disk? I have an external disk that is already partitioned, formatted, and has grub installed.

Comment: It's possible to boot an ISO from Grub.

Comment: Possible with debootstrap. but not sure about how to do that with an EFI system. You can find a tutorial on my blog, its linked in my profile. just that was made for using legacy boot.

Comment: Try this... https://askubuntu.com/questions/967693/reinstall-no-cd-or-usb/968743#968743